# How to integrate Cucumber into Code to Test Ratio?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, cucumber, bdd

When I use "rake stats" I can get to know how many lines of code I have written for my RSpec tests. And my RSpec tests influences also the Code to Test Ratio.

But can I list my lines of code from the Cucumber steps there, too?

Best regards

Answer (score 1):

One cucumber step can do an awful lot of work, I don't think adding it to your code/test ratio would actually make sense.  What information is it giving you?  What if you are executing multiple dependent steps?

Cucumber tests are integration tests, they are not a replacement for controller/unit tests, but are to be done in conjunction with them.

You might be more interested in the resulting code coverage obtained by your cucumber tests, this will be a far more useful metric.

Comment: I agree. Code to Test Ratio is a fun metric but it's not necessarily the most useful. Unless you have a strong need for it, you're better off looking at things like your overall code coverage and the like.

Answer (score 0):

See [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1613655/rake-stats-and-cucumber/1613689#1613689). It's as simple as adding two lines of code to rspec.rake file.