# Rake stats and Cucumber

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, cucumber

I'm using Cucumber with RSpec in a Rails project.
When I use the "rake stats" task, I get the following :

```
+----------------------+-------+-------+---------+---------+-----+-------+
| Name                 | Lines |   LOC | Classes | Methods | M/C | LOC/M |
+----------------------+-------+-------+---------+---------+-----+-------+
| Controllers          |   948 |   761 |      21 |      87 |   4 |     6 |
| Helpers              |   212 |   175 |       0 |      24 |   0 |     5 |
| Models               |   912 |   741 |      28 |      72 |   2 |     8 |
| Libraries            |   305 |   211 |       1 |      25 |  25 |     6 |
| Model specs          |   978 |   797 |       0 |       1 |   0 |   795 |
| View specs           |   270 |   227 |       0 |       0 |   0 |     0 |
| Controller specs     |  1144 |   944 |       0 |       4 |   0 |   234 |
| Helper specs         |   154 |   116 |       0 |       0 |   0 |     0 |
+----------------------+-------+-------+---------+---------+-----+-------+
| Total                |  4923 |  3972 |      50 |     213 |   4 |    16 |
+----------------------+-------+-------+---------+---------+-----+-------+
  Code LOC: 1888     Test LOC: 2084     Code to Test Ratio: 1:1.1
```

So rspec adds its stats (see the model, view, controller and helper specs).
But I don't have the cucumber ones. How could I add them to my rake stats ?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

RSpec creates a `lib/tasks/rspec.rake` file. And redefines the stats directories inside of it.

At the line 108 of that file, you'll see :

```
# Setup specs for stats
task :statsetup do
    require 'code_statistics'
    ::STATS_DIRECTORIES << %w(Model\ specs spec/models) if File.exist?('spec/models')
    ::STATS_DIRECTORIES << %w(View\ specs spec/views) if File.exist?('spec/views')
    ....
end
```

You just need to add your cucumber features directory there, right before the end of the task.

```
#
# Adding Cucumber features to the stats
#
::STATS_DIRECTORIES << %w(Cucumber\ features features) if File.exist?('features')
::CodeStatistics::TEST_TYPES << "Cucumber features" if File.exist?('features')
```

Comment: Woh that was quick ! I'm checking that.

Comment: Any tips on how to do this if you're not using rspec?

Comment: Could you tell us how that works with the latest rspec-2 gem? Because there is no rake task

Answer (score 2):

Why monkey patch the gem like that? You'll have to add your fix for it every time you update rspec-rails. Just extend the task locally with something like this:

```
echo "# Adding Cucumber features to be reported by the command:
# rake stats
# But e.g. in production environment we probably don't have rspec-rails, nor it's
# statsetup task, we could extend. So lets check if stasetup is available and only
# then extend it. If it isn't then just do nothing.
if Rake::Task.task_defined? 'spec:statsetup'
  Rake::Task['spec:statsetup'].enhance do
    require 'rails/code_statistics'
    ::STATS_DIRECTORIES << %w(Cucumber\ features features) if File.exist?('features')
    ::CodeStatistics::TEST_TYPES << 'Cucumber features' if File.exist?('features')
  end
end" > lib/tasks/cucumber_stats.rake
```

And FYI Lichtamberg and Damien MATHIEU this works just fine with rspec 2. However these rails specific rake tasks are ofc not part of the rspec gem itself, but a part of the rspec-rails gem.

P.S. This all was tested with ruby 1.9.2p180 (2011-02-18 revision 30909) [i686-linux], rails 3.0.8, rspec 2.6.0 and rspec-rails 2.6.1 and it might or might not work older versions of them.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a version that works with Turnip and RSpec 2

https://gist.github.com/2360892

Answer (score 0):

```
I copy paste my custom set up for RSpec 1:

+----------------------+-------+-------+---------+---------+-----+-------+
| Name                 | Lines |   LOC | Classes | Methods | M/C | LOC/M |
+----------------------+-------+-------+---------+---------+-----+-------+
| Controllers          |  1110 |   791 |      39 |      92 |   2 |     6 |
| Helpers              |   449 |   373 |       0 |      39 |   0 |     7 |
| Models               |  1986 |  1338 |      25 |     111 |   4 |    10 |
| Libraries            |   652 |   479 |      11 |      41 |   3 |     9 |
| Views                |  2911 |  2730 |       0 |       0 |   0 |     0 |
| Static CSS           |  2776 |  2174 |       0 |       0 |   0 |     0 |
| App javascript       |    16 |    14 |       0 |       0 |   0 |     0 |
| Model specs          |   517 |   289 |       0 |       2 |   0 |   142 |
| Helper specs         |    27 |    22 |       0 |       0 |   0 |     0 |
| Library specs        |    31 |    24 |       0 |       0 |   0 |     0 |
| Cucumber features    |   907 |   657 |       3 |      13 |   4 |    48 |
+----------------------+-------+-------+---------+---------+-----+-------+
| Total                | 11382 |  8891 |      78 |     298 |   3 |    27 |
+----------------------+-------+-------+---------+---------+-----+-------+
  Code LOC: 7899     Test LOC: 992     Code to Test Ratio: 1:0.1
```

Code:

```
# here is my set up
    task :statsetup do
      require 'code_statistics'

      class CodeStatistics
        alias calculate_statistics_orig calculate_statistics

        def calculate_statistics
          @pairs.inject({}) do |stats, pair|
            if 3 == pair.size
              stats[pair.first] = calculate_directory_statistics(pair[1], pair[2]); stats
            else
              stats[pair.first] = calculate_directory_statistics(pair.last); stats
            end
          end
        end
      end
      # http://www.pervasivecode.com/blog/2007/06/28/hacking-rakestats-to-get-gross-loc/
      ::STATS_DIRECTORIES << ['Views', 'app/views', /\.(rhtml|erb|rb)$/]
      ::STATS_DIRECTORIES << ['Static CSS',  'public/stylesheets', /\.css$/]
      ::STATS_DIRECTORIES << ['App javascript',  'public/javascripts', /application.js$/]

      # RSpec default
      ::STATS_DIRECTORIES << %w( Model\ specs spec/models ) if File.exist?('spec/models')
      ::STATS_DIRECTORIES << %w( View\ specs spec/views ) if File.exist?('spec/views')
      ::STATS_DIRECTORIES << %w( Controller\ specs spec/controllers ) if File.exist?('spec/controllers')
      ::STATS_DIRECTORIES << %w( Helper\ specs spec/helpers ) if File.exist?('spec/helpers')
      ::STATS_DIRECTORIES << %w( Library\ specs spec/lib ) if File.exist?('spec/lib')
      ::STATS_DIRECTORIES << %w( Routing\ specs spec/routing ) if File.exist?('spec/routing')
      ::STATS_DIRECTORIES << %w( Integration\ specs spec/integration ) if File.exist?('spec/integration')
      ::CodeStatistics::TEST_TYPES << "Model specs" if File.exist?('spec/models')
      ::CodeStatistics::TEST_TYPES << "View specs" if File.exist?('spec/views')
      ::CodeStatistics::TEST_TYPES << "Controller specs" if File.exist?('spec/controllers')
      ::CodeStatistics::TEST_TYPES << "Helper specs" if File.exist?('spec/helpers')
      ::CodeStatistics::TEST_TYPES << "Library specs" if File.exist?('spec/lib')
      ::CodeStatistics::TEST_TYPES << "Routing specs" if File.exist?('spec/routing')
      ::CodeStatistics::TEST_TYPES << "Integration specs" if File.exist?('spec/integration')

      # Cuke
      ::STATS_DIRECTORIES << %w( Cucumber\ features features ) if File.exist?('features')
      ::CodeStatistics::TEST_TYPES << "Cucumber features" if File.exist?('features')

    end
```

Answer (score 0):

Although this is an extremely old question, it is still first when googling "rails rake stats cucumber" and the answers are misleading or outdated.

For future googlers, all you need to do is run

```
$ rails generate cucumber:install
```

This will create the necessary files, and specifically the `lib/tasks/cucumber.rake` file, which adds "Cucumber Features" to the `rake stats` output.