# Custom rake:stats

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, rspec

How do I make a custom `rake:stats` so that I can examine the number of lines of code in a different directory?

For example, I have a app/workers directory for my resque workers, that I would like to profile.

I'm using rspec. I want something along the lines of [Rake stats and Cucumber](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1613655/rake-stats-and-cucumber), but I don't have a `/lib/tasks/rspec.rake`

Comment: maybe this helps ? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1613655/rake-stats-and-cucumber

Comment: I tried that, but I got `rake aborted!
undefined method `calculate_statistics' for class `CodeStatistics'

Tasks: TOP => statsetup`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sorry I don't know how to edit rake stats. But you could try this script in terminal on Mac, for example counting LOC in views directory:

```
find app/views -name "*html.erb" -exec wc -l {} \;
```

Hope that helps

Answer (score 4):

[This article](http://ridingtheclutch.com/post/71345006944/how-to-add-directories-to-rake-stats) shows how to do it:

```
task :stats => "omakase:stats"

namespace :omakase do
  task :stats do
    require 'rails/code_statistics'
    ::STATS_DIRECTORIES << ["Services", "app/services"]
    ::STATS_DIRECTORIES << ["Services Tests", "test/services"]
    CodeStatistics::TEST_TYPES << 'Services Tests'
  end
end
```